# Update with transient object in hibernate with known primary key

Tags: java, hibernate

I currently have a jsf page where I have form inputs. This inputs directly set the variables in a Student object in the controller bean. Student is a hibernate entity mapped to a database table. Currently, the users can select which student they want to edit. The id(primary key) of the selected student is stored. When the user enters the form fields, a new student object A(does not have id set) gets submitted. Is it possible to set the primary key variable in the transient object A and update the corresponding record in the database. Currently, I am using get method to get another Student object B with the ID. Copy the values from A to B then merge B to update database.

Comment: *My question is can I set the stored ID in Student object A and update it in the database directly with hibernate* - why don't you try it and see?

Comment: No I have tried it. Because object A is transient, it adds a new record to the database instead of updating an existing record.

Comment: you should be able to put your object back into the persistence context to save it properly : try reloading it, and merging it afterwards. But AFAIK, you can't change the `Id` field of a managed entity, Hibernate won't let you do it. Show your code for a more accurate answer